# Email link target changed in mailinator

Tags: links, mailinator

I have generated a mail from my website which has some link with `target` specified as `_blank`

```
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_blank">foo</a>
```

but when i checked in mailinator, it was changed to `_other`

```
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_other">foo</a>
```

So, can anyone tell me why it's changed and how to prevent it from changing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the way Mailinator processes all hyperlinks. I sent emails to a Mailinator account with links that had three different `target` settings:

```
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_blank">foo</a>
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_new">foo</a>
<a href="http://foo.com" target="_self">foo</a>
```

All three showed up in the Mailinator inbox as `target="_other"`.  All three also opened up in a new tab, just as `target="_blank"` would do.

If you want to contact Mailinator support to ask them about why they do that or see if they have a workaround (though I'm not sure what the use case for needing one would be) their email is ***support@manybrain.com***.